# Where can I find bluemix programmer(s) for contract work?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have some work I need completed on the bluemix platform and need contractors to complete it? I will have a constant flow flow of work. Any advice/recommendations greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look on StackOverflow careers!!!

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

They have a database full of awesome programmer... If you don't like it, you can look for programmers who specialize in certain fields (such as BlueMix API usage) in sites such as:

- Freelancer - https://www.freelancer.com/
- Elance - https://mobile.elance.com/m/
- And any other freelancing sites

### Leave a comment below if you have any questions, or require further assistance.